# How can I recover a Mac HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

Should I take it out and put it in a HDD enclosure. assuming its a 2.5" drive, should i buy a HDD enclosure and just slot it in?
Anyone know of a half decent FAQ that will help me with this task.
Finally any special gotchas when reconnecting this external drive to my iMac desktop machine? Do i have to use firewire or can I use USB 2?
Sorry for what seems like lots of questions but they are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No special firmware. No gotchas. USB 2 will work 'out of the box'. Just slot it in a 2.5 inch HDD enclosure (assuming it's a 2.5 HDD) and away you go.

The company that makes the external HDD enclosure you choose will provide instructions regarding how to put the HDD in the enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the circumstances of the corrupted drive, but what I've always done is used Apple's Disk Utility to first determine the extent of the corruption.
If the machine is not bootable, then boot using the OS X install DVD.
If Disk Utility cannot correct the error, then you're probably in for purchasing a recovery utility. I have not found a free one.

Answer (score 1):

iMac HDDs are generally 3.5". Any enclosure for that size either with USB or Firewire should be fine. [Here is a link](http://www.finiteloops.com/weblog/?p=7) to couple of recovery software. [This website](http://www.ifixit.com/) has several useful guides on how to replace your HDD.